# How to give temporary domain name in intranet?

Tags: networking, dns, ip

In my system I have installed tomcat and to run a web application I use `http://localhost:8080/app`

and if another person present in my intranet network wants to access my application then I give my ip add like below

```
http://192.168.1.3:8080/app
```

The problem is my ip is changing very frequently(after system restart) sometimes it is 3,sometimes it is 100 and sometimes some other ip.The problem I am facing is when ever my ip is changed other are unable to access unless I provide them my new Ip address.

So I am thinking to give them a temporary domain name like `

> > *http://myAPP:8080/app*

so when ever My Ip is changed they will not face any problem

So I tried modifying the hosts file present in C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc like the following

```
127.0.0.1               myApp
```

But in this case I am able to access the url `http://myApp:8080/app` only in my system but others present in my network unable to access.

So can any body please tell me how to give a temporary domain.

**Note**:I can make my system a static IP but I want to use this way(by giving a temporary domain Name)

Comment: The Hosts file is local, everyone would have to add that entry to their Hosts file for it to work.

Comment: Whether you do hosts file, or set up a local dns server, you really should use a static DHCP setting for that machine hosting that web application. That will make whatever option you choose much easier to maintain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have an hostname for your machine that always corresponds to its dynamic IP address, you will need either to have a DNS server somewhere (with some dynamic DNS system), or to use another way of resolving the name. Editing the `hosts` file is not a solution, as you would need to edit it on all machines, and to change it every time the IP address changes. Never tried, but there might be a way to publish a private IP on some public dynamic DNS services (supposing your network has Internet connectivity).

Who (which device) is giving the IP addresses to the computers in your network? Some of them (e.g., some home routers) also have an integrated DNS server and can resolve names to IP addresses if you explicitly create some association in the configuration (e.g. MAC address XX-YY-ZZ-AA-BB-CC is named myApp).

In a Windows-only environment, the computer name could generally be used for your purpose. The OS sends a network broadcast (using the NetBIOS name service protocol over UDP), to check if any computer with the given name exists. Try if `http://NAME:8080/app` works (where *NAME* is the Windows computer name of the system hosting the application). You might have to enable NetBIOS over TCP/IP on your machines for this to work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer +1,so do you think it is  not possible to get if I change hosts file in my system?

Comment: It would be possible if you change the hosts file in **all** the systems that have to access your application, but **only** if you use a static IP address. There is no reason to use a dynamic IP on a machine that exposes services, except of course if you have no other choice. But as you're in a LAN, I guess you could set a static IP (or configure the DHCP server to always give the same IP to the machine).

Comment: I have upvoted your answer,can you do that for my question too?